# How do I print the full result of a matrix multiplication in a Maple for loop?

Tags: matrices, maple

How do I print the full result without the u1, u2, … variables using a for loop?
I tried declaring my two matrix this way:

[Capture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4OT0.png)

[Capture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwH96.png)

It executes my for loop until u11 but doesn’t return the vector 
Then I tried to change my multiplication for a multiply

[Capture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wijkQ.png)

It also does the for loop completely but doesn’t print the vector like u1 in the last example.
Then I tried declaring my two matrixes with an array:

[Capture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT0Wl.png)

[Capture 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEKWW.png)

It does the for completely but doesn’t print the vectors like u1
I change my multiplication for A.u[i] but it ain’t working either
Then I tried to declare the matrix with Matrix and the vector with Vector

[Capture 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPRdH.png)

[Capture 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk1C2.png)

It doesn’t work….

It’s always the first vector u1 that prints correctly and the others aren’t doing the multiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that you are not using the correct syntax for assigning a result to a name.

Inside you loops, you have statements like this,

```
u[i+1] = A.u[i];
```

Such a statement constructs an equation, and does nothing else with it. Nothing is being assigned here.

What you seem to have expected was actual assignment that a statement like this would accomplish,

```
u[i+1] := A.u[i];
```

Comment: It solved it thanks a lot @acer